# Как переписать путь к папке?

Tags: angular2, iis

Подключаю файлы ангуляра, в конфиге указываю папку в которой лежит мой скрипт

```
app: 'app',
```

при обычном хосте проекта на ИИСе под урлом типа: `http://localhost:57927/` всё работает идеально. Однако стоит мне разместить проект на ИИСе по урлу `http://localhost/fgWeb/` (такое требование) - сразу консольная ошибка `GET http://localhost/app/main.js 404 (Not Found)`. В `Source` не добавляется папка `app`.

Мне кажется что нужно что-то предпринять со строчкой указывающей папку (сверху моего сообщения), однако я не знаю что.

Answer (score 0):

Настройте `<base href="">`

В `href` пропишите адрес приложения типа `href="/app/"`